# request.setAttribute is not overriding with new valuie in servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have servlet portion that receives HttpServletRequest  like below

```
public ActionForward execute(
        ActionMapping mapping,
        ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    if (request.getParameter("STATE").equalsIgnoreCase("TX")) {
        request.setAttribute("STATE", "IL");
    }
    System.out.println("Printing " + request.getParameter("STATE"));
}
```

The code I wrote is When I am passing STATE as 'TX', its coming inside if block and overriding state as IL.

But the new value is not overriding, I am always getting TX. I need to replace the TX with IL once i received request as TX.

Please help me

Comment: You get a parameter, and you set an attribute. Those are not the same thing. A parameter is a string, and it comes from the browser, inside the request (in the URL for GET, in the body for POST). An attribute is any piece of information that you want, on the server, attach to the request.

Comment: Is there any method to set parameter, overriding with new value.  For this request object I have to change to IL.

Comment: If you'd do `request.getAttribute()` then you'd get IL back.

Comment: No, there is no setParameter(), as it wouldn't make sense. Parameters are input.

Comment: I believe your `ActionForm` is binded to front end controls so a property in the form will be binded to jsp/html control. So why cant you manipulate the form property rather than using request

Comment: you can do a redirect with the new value of the parameter. To do this you need to create a new url string with all the information from the current request, except the value for the STATE parameter which you need to set it to IL and then send a redirect to the newly created url

Answer (score 0):

First your using request.getParmater("TX") according to the param value you are setting the request.setAttribute("STATE","IL") inside the if block and outside the if block again you are using the request.getParameter("STATE").

Note:
here you are not overriding  according to param name you are setting the some attribute in request. request parameters are immutable you cant change it

Answer (score 0):

In your if-condition, You are setting/overriding attribute and you are printing parameter, So you are not getting updating value.

You can't change request-parameter from HttpServletRequest, so you need to use attribute for modifying request.

Please change your code to

```
if (request.getParameter("STATE") != null && request.getParameter("STATE").equalsIgnoreCase("TX")) {
    // If request contains TX, then add updated STATE in attribute
    request.setAttribute("STATE", "IL");
} else {
    // If request doesn't contains or contains other than TX then add previous status in attribute
    request.setAttribute("STATE", request.getParameter("STATE"));
}
// Now we are using attribute instead of parameter
System.out.println("Printing " + request.getAttribute("STATE"));
```